# how to pass check box values to a submit button ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using php and ajax to build a check box form that allows users to sumbit values after clicking a submit button. When the sumbit button is clicked, then the values of the check box is passed to a php file using ajax.

**The Question**
How do I pass the values of the check boxes when the button is clicked?

```
    <!-------------------ajax part no problem here--------------->
   <script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax-php.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
 } </script> <!-------------------ajax part no problem here--------------->

<form>
   <!------- problem here----------->
    <input type="checkbox" name="users"  value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="users"  value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="users"  value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="users"  value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="users"  value="5">

    <input type="button" onclick="showUser(this.value)">
    <!------- problem here----------->
</form>

<div id="txtHint"><b>RESULTS WILL BE LISED HERE...</b></div>
```

**THANKS** IN ADVANCE

Comment: you should try like `<input type="checkbox" name="users[]"  value="1">`

Comment: In the xmlhttp.send function you can add the URI with the vars of the checkboxes. For example if 1 and 3 are checked, something like:

`xmlhttp.send(encodeURI('users[]=1&users[]=3'))`

Comment: thanks for the response, I kindly ask if you would be able to demonstrate? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="showUser($(\"input[name='users']:checked\").val())">
```

Comment: Hmmm its cleaver but it doesnt seem to work, I've tried name="users[]" and name="users" for the checkboxes with your code

Comment: then i will prefer call `code` showUser() without parameter  and in you function before ajax calling use: 

`code` var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('users[]');
var str = "";
for (var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) 
{
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) 
    {
        str += ","+checkboxes[i].value;
    }
}

 `code` ajax-php.php?q=str

Answer (score 0):

Check the below snippet. I have added an additional snippet to help you get which checkboxes are checked and which are unchecked:

```js
function showUser(str) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    
    /** additional code to help **/
    var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('users[]');
    var len = cboxes.length;
    var str = '';
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var checkOrUncheck = cboxes[i].checked ? 'checked':'unchecked';
        str += '&' + i + '=' + checkOrUncheck;
    }
    console.log(str);
    /** additional code to help ends here **/
    
    
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax-php.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<form>
  <!------- problem here----------->
  <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="5">

  <input type="button" onclick="showUser()">
  <!------- problem here----------->
</form>

<div id="txtHint"><b>RESULTS WILL BE LISED HERE...</b></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Milan Chheda for your efforts, It makes perfect sense, but the value is not passing to the php page. I am echoing the following the the triggered php page -- $q = intval($_GET['q']);
 echo $q ;--

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion if you like, you don't need an ajax.

```
    <form method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="users" value="5">

  <input type="button" name="Submit">
</form>
```

then you can call the button listener by:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
 echo $_POST[user];
}
```

and then you can store the value to an array.